# Meteor: Retrieving images within collections

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

I'm writing to this collection:

```
GiftCards = new Mongo.Collection('giftcards');

GiftCards.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    cardType: {
        type: String
    },
    cardValue: {
        type: Number,
        defaultValue: 100
    },
    fileId: {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "fileUpload",
                collection: "Images"
            }
        }
    }
}));

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "public/uploads"})]
});
```

With a form made with AutoForm.

```
 {{> quickForm collection="GiftCards" id="giftCardsForm" type="insert"}}
```

Data is written, but I don't find a way to show the image associated with every document in the collection......I have only the id (in fileId) and don't find the way to publish correctly image with specific documents it refers...

Comment: Have you check out the CollectionFS [documentation](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#display-an-uploaded-image)?

Comment: Yes, but I think the problem is more about mongodb  and relationship - I don't know well NoSQL.....with MySQL I make a join and take what I need....

Comment: Then could you share the pub sub code you've written to send data to the client? Maybe something is wrong there ..

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Digital-Steel/70bc09da635a5cf0b33fea26b89e00c1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `GiftCards` collection includes a single foreign key reference to the `Images` collection as `fileId`. This is actually just like SQL in the sense that the primary key of the `Images` collection is used as a foreign key in `GiftCards`.

Now you want to display a gift card and its related single image.

```
<template name="showOneGiftCard">
  Type: {{type}}, value: {{value}} <img src={{url}}/>
</template>
```

Then you need a helper to return the url of the image:

```
Template.showOneGiftCard.helpers({
  url: function(){
    var img = Images.findOne(this.fileId); // 'this' is the data context of one GiftCard
    return img && img.url(); // will return undefined if there's no attached image
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, but if I want to have ALL GiftCards list using a {{ #each gift cards }} ?

Comment: `{{#each giftCards}}{{> showOneGiftCard}}{{/each}}` then just make a `giftCards` helper that returns `GiftCards.find()`

Comment: ok done, but with let img = Images.findOne(this.fileId); // 'this' is the data context of one GiftCard give "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'img' " and without give: "Failed to load resource:"

Comment: The problem is probably with token and security

Comment: Are you in Meteor 1.2 or 1.3? If the former then `var img = ` instead of `let img = `. Also make sure your images are published and available on the client. This has nothing to do with tokens/security. I use this pattern all the time.